# Button onclick - WebView loadURL? (Android app)

Tags: android

I'm having trouble loading a URL using WebView in the app. In the initial screen I'll have two textfields and one button. (All the fields are defined in res/layouts/main.xml file). When the button is clicked, a method will be called in the Activity class where I'll validate the textfields and load a URL using WebView.. When I run the application I get an exception which I couldn't able to fix.. Would be great if someone could be help me to resolve this issue. Any pointers would be highly appreciated..

I've pasted the source code and the exception trace for your reference..

Main.xml file,

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/userName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/loginbutton"
    android:layout_width="212dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="logMe"
    android:text="Login" />

<WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView" />
```

Activity Class,

```
public void logMe(View view){
    un = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);
    pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    Toast.makeText(this,"Hello "+un.getText().toString()+ " Your password is:  "+pwd.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if(un.getText().toString().equals("admin")){
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onExceededDatabaseQuota(String url, String
                databaseIdentifier, long currentQuota, long estimatedSize,
                long totalUsedQuota, WebStorage.QuotaUpdater quotaUpdater) {
            quotaUpdater.updateQuota(estimatedSize * 2); // try to keep quota size as big as possible else database will not get created in HTML 5 app
        }});
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();  
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        String dbPath = this.getApplicationContext().getDir("database", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath();
        //String dbPath ="/data/data/com.android.HTML5DBExample/databases/";
        settings.setDatabasePath(dbPath);
        settings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);    


        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/newUI.html");
    }
```

Below is the exception trace in LogCat,

```
12-03 15:47:04.367: E/AndroidRuntime(666): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-03 15:47:04.367: E/AndroidRuntime(666): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
12-03 15:47:04.367: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2683)
12-03 15:47:04.367: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
12-03 15:47:04.367: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11934)
12-03 15:47:04.367: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-03 15:47:04.367: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-03 15:47:04.367: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
12-03 15:47:04.367: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
12-03 15:47:04.367: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-03 15:47:04.367: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
12-03 15:47:04.367: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
12-03 15:47:04.367: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
12-03 15:47:04.367: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-03 15:47:04.367: E/AndroidRuntime(666): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-03 15:47:04.367: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-03 15:47:04.367: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
12-03 15:47:04.367: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2678)
12-03 15:47:04.367: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  ... 11 more
12-03 15:47:04.367: E/AndroidRuntime(666): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-03 15:47:04.367: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at com.android.httpurlproject.HttpURLProjectActivity.logMe(HttpURLProjectActivity.java:49)
12-03 15:47:04.367: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  ... 14 more
```

Comment: Can you tell us which line is 49?

Comment: This is the 49th line in the code "webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {"

Comment: Hmm, do you have a WebView inside your layout, right?

Comment: yeaaah.. I've WebView in the main.xml. Check out main.xml file tht I've pasted above.

Comment: Clean your project (Project > Clean from the Eclipse main menu, or `ant clean` from the command line), and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. I created a new Project and copy-pasted the code that I needed and it worked fine :))